# JavaScript - Zero value in a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database

I have a problem with my Javascript code.

I have a php code that gets the value from the database.

Example values are : 00027, 0208

When I put it in a function like

```
$id = 00027; 

<input type='submit' onclick='CheckPat($id)'> 

function CheckPat(x){ 
    alert(x); // returns 23 and for 0208 returns 208 
    //desired output 00027 and 0208
 }
```

the problem here is I believe that when I put the variable `$id` with integer value it rounds and it removes the zero. How can I return my desired value?

Comment: Are you able to set the variables as a string instead of a number?  That would retain leading zeros.

Comment: Have a look at [`String.prototype.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Comment: `onclick='CheckPat($id)'` looks for a **JavaScript** variable called `$id`. If you want to use the PHP variable, you need to `echo` it.

Comment: number beginning with `0` are treated as `octal` ... `27` octal = `2 * 8 + 7` = `23`

Comment: Just curious, but why do you need to pass the values with those leading zeros? What do the values represent in your data and/or where are the numbers coming from?

Comment: @Mark the values is my unique id in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$id` is a numeric value but your desired output is special `String` formatted value of `$id` value thus
you must do some `javascript` side calculation for the number like below:

```js
function CheckPat(x) {
  x = parseInt(x);
  if (x < 10)
    alert("0000" + x);
  else if (x < 100)
    alert("000" + x);
  else if (x < 1000)
    alert("00" + x);
  else if (x < 10000)
    alert("0" + x);
  else
    alert(x);
}
```

```html
Given value:<input id='val' value="0027" />
<button type='button' onclick='CheckPat(document.getElementById("val").value)'>Check It!</button>
```

But if you want forward `$id` value to `CheckPat` function directly simply add the double quotation to `onclick` event like below:

```
...
<input type='submit' onclick='CheckPat("$id")'> 
...
```

Comment: You're welcome.But I will glad if you vote up my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use numbers as a string.

```
    $id = 00027;    

    to    

    $id = '00027'; 

    OR 

    $id.toString();

    <input type='submit' onclick='CheckPat($id)'> 

    function CheckPat(x){ 
        alert(x); // returns 23 and for 0208 returns 208 
        //desired output 00027 and 0208
     }
```

Actually, when we use numbers like 00027 and 0208, JS treats these numbers as a number systems  `base-16 (hexadecimal), base-8 (octal)` etc.

Comment: actually, you need `0x` prefix for base-16 ... and leading 0 alone will give an octal (unless you have a 8 or 9 in the number - then a syntax error is output in the console, but the assignment succeeds) - and a lesser known syntax is `0b[01]+` ... i.e. binary

Answer (score 0):

You should use a string instead of a number type. In PHP:

```
$id = '00027';
```

In a string of JavaScript inside a string of HTML inside a double-quoted PHP string:

```
<input type='submit' onclick=\"CheckPat('$id')\">
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use num.toString()

```js
You should use numbers as a string.


<input type='submit' onclick='CheckPat($id.toString())'> 

function CheckPat(x){ 
    alert(x); // returns 23 and for 0208 returns 208 
    //desired output 00027 and 0208
 }
```

Comment: the leading zeros are lost at `$id = 00027` ... so, `toString` won't help

Comment: This would be a syntax error, `$id..toString()` isn't an error, but wouldn't help for the reason @JaromandaX stated.